# Echo variable using sudo bash -c 'echo $myVariable' - bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to echo a string into the */etc/hosts* file. The string is stored in a variable called `$myString`.

When I run the following code the echo is empty:

```
finalString="Hello\nWorld"
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "$finalString"'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're not exporting the variable into the environment so that it can be picked up by subprocesses.
2. You haven't told `sudo` to preserve the environment.

\

```
finalString="Hello\nWorld"
export finalString
sudo -E bash -c 'echo -e "$finalString"'
```

Alternatively, you can have the current shell substitute instead:

```
finalString="Hello\nWorld"
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "'"$finalString"'"'
```

Comment: That is: using `export` makes variables available in the sub-shells.

Comment: to export the variable into the environment is it just 'export finalString'? Because it's still not printing the variable.

Comment: @user2771150 you probably need `-E` in sudo --> `sudo -E bash -c 'echo -e "$finalString"'`.

Comment: are they both 'safe'? is there a 'recommended' way? sorry. I'm pretty new to bash scripting.

Comment: if you echo to a file with sudo bash -c 'echo -e "'"$finalString"'" > your_text_file', then it is better to go for the alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
bash -c "echo -e '$finalString'"
```

i.e using double quote to pass argument to the subshell, thus the variable (`$finalString`) is expanded (by the current shell) as expected.

Though I would recommend not using the `-e` flag with `echo`. Instead you can just do:

```
finalString="Hello
World"
```