# Echo variable from csv with string using a bash script in terminal

Tags: bash, csv, variables, terminal, escaping

I believe there's some similar posts that if I was better at this I could figure out the answer to my own question ([This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-to-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes?newreg=73b7e85d3f154e0e9c12c3776f9000c4) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004340/echo-variable-using-sudo-bash-c-echo-myvariable-bash-script)).

I have a Mac and am using the **setfile** command from the terminal which works great on an individual file.

`setfile -d "08/02/2001 00:00:00" X-09-04.m4v`

However, I have hundreds of videos to do this with. I have a file **changedate.csv** file with all the dates and associated file names in two separate columns (screenshot). The csv is formatted like this:

```
datenew,id
12/19/1998 12:00:00 AM,X-01/X-01-01.m4v
12/31/1998 12:00:00 AM,X-01/X-01-02.m4v
12/31/1998 12:00:00 AM,X-01/X-01-03.m4v
```

I then created **changedate.sh** script that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat changedate.csv | while IFS=, read datenew id;
do
    echo 'setfile -d "$datenew" $id'
done
```

The command setfile requires the date string needs to be wrapped in quotes. This is what messes me up, because when I run **sh changedate.sh** script from the terminal, it prints out like this:

```
setfile -d "$datenew" $id
setfile -d "$datenew" $id
setfile -d "$datenew" $id
....
```

If I remove the quotes around the variable it correctly reads the csv and the output looks like this:

```
setfile -d 12/19/1998 00:00:00  X-01/X-01-01.m4v
setfile -d 12/31/1998 00:00:00  X-01/X-01-02.m4v
setfile -d 12/31/1998 00:00:00  X-01/X-01-03.m4v
...
```

This is almost right, but it doesn't work because the date string isn't wrapped in quotes which is required. The final output should look like this:

```
setfile -d "12/19/1998 00:00:00"  X-01/X-01-01.m4v
setfile -d "12/31/1998 00:00:00"  X-01/X-01-02.m4v
setfile -d "12/31/1998 00:00:00"  X-01/X-01-03.m4v
...
```

I think I need to use backslashes to get the variable to print with the quotes, but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you echoing the `setfile` command instead of just executing it?

Comment: `setfile` itself does not need (or see) the quotes; those are just to protect the space between the date and the time from word-splitting. If you plan on actually running the command, `setfile -d "$datenew" "$id"` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. So you need to put double quotes around the argument to `echo`.

```
echo "setfile -d '$datenew' '$id'"
```